# How to update ListView dynamically when user selects a different date?

Tags: firebase, listview, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

For an app I'm building, I want the user to be able to enter a specific date through the CupertinoDatePicker shown below, and immediately after I want the list view below to update dynamically. The list view should show all the posts which have a timestamp that *falls between* the specified date from the user.

[image: app ui]

Here is how my data is structured in firestore. Essentially I have a **user collection** and each individual user has a few attributes such as their name, grade, etc along with a **sub-collection** of *posts*. Each post records information that a user fills out in a form, but most importantly it logs the timestamp when the post was submitted. Here's a screenshot for clarity.

[image: firestore data structure]

The problem I'm facing is that the list view wouldn't update when the user decides to select a different date. My code is shown below.

```
         Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _firestore
                      .collectionGroup('posts')
                      .where('timestamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start)
                      .where('timestamp', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      return Center(child: Text("No Users"));
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemExtent: 80.0,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildListItem(
                          context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

*_start* and *_end* are calculated when the user selects a different date.

```
child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                initialDateTime: _dateTime,
                use24hFormat: false,
                onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dateTime = val;
                    _start = DateTime(
                      _dateTime.year,
                      _dateTime.month,
                      _dateTime.day,
                      0,
                      0,
                    );
                    _end = DateTime(
                      _dateTime.year,
                      _dateTime.month,
                      _dateTime.day,
                      23,
                      59,
                      59,
                    );
                  });
                  print(val);
                  print(_dateTime);
                },
              ),
```

Please advise on how I would resolve my issue. I've been searching for several days on how to fix this problem, but I had no success. Any help or suggestion is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never call the function to fetch the data when you change the dates. On the `onDateTimeChanged` after you change the dates you don't call a function to retrieve any data from firebase. **Streambuilder** listens to events coming from the stream not from your variables.

You can have your stream as a state variable and when you change your date change your stream and the data will be refreshed.

Comment: Wouldn't _start and _end change though? I update their values in the setState function when the user changes the date. As a result wouldn't new data from firebase be fetched because I run this query: .where('timestamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start).where('timestamp', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end)

Comment: A streambuilder instance always subscribes to the stream passed to it.

Comment: I coded up what you suggested, but now the data doesn't show up. I made a state variable *postsStream* and updated it in the setState inside ```onDateTimeChanged```. I changed the stream attribute in the StreamBuilder to *postsStream*. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Create a gist for me and send it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aryanvichare/77c9e19aad6d5f6a5211b66d078f8846

Comment: Update - I got the initial data to show up. But when I change the date, the list view doesn't refresh/rebuild.

Comment: Hmm, i just tested with a period streambuilder and it worked. Give me a sec to send you a dart pad.

Comment: Hit run, when you click change it gets data from the other stream.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it first thing in the morning and reply back.

Comment: Hmm ok, I believe Stream<T>.periodic() has a different use case to emit events every set period of time. Upon the date changed, I immediately update my _postsStream with a new _start time and _end time in a setState(). The behavior I'm seeing goes as follows: When I first log into the dashboard, the expected behavior works (ex. no users found for March 19th), however for any other date, I see two cards even though both were created on March 18th. Why isn't my _postsStream getting updated to listen to a new stream of data?